# git branches are very confusing for me (creating new branches, features)

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I've tried to create feature branch in GIT.
What I trying to create

```
A -- B -- C ------ D
      \
       E --
```

Where first line is development, second line is feature branch.

How I need to create feature branch? Like this?

```
git checkout -d myFeature
```

After changing files:

```
git add .
git commit -m "My awesome commit"
```

And then push

```
git push origin myFeature
```

Merge in dev branch

```
git merge myFeature
```

And then commit and push again. Is this a right way?
Can a branch created from commit?
What means --track flag in GIT and when i need to use it?
What is the difference between branch and origin/branch?

Can somebody explain me about branches?

Comment: You need a good tutorial. There are a lot of *bad* tutorials and you may have learned something from some of them that is simply not true.  For a good tutorial you can start with the Pro Git book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: *Do* read that book --^ when you get a chance. Although it's a little heavy at some parts, and doesn't hold your hand as much as some beginners might appreciate. Here's [an excellent **free** interactive course](https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I need to create feature branch?

If you're trying to create `myFeature` branch from commit hash `B`

```
git checkout -b myFeature B
```

**Note** the syntax error in your posted question `error: unknown switch 'd'`

> Merge in dev branch

Don't forget to checkout your `dev` branch *first*, and then merge `myFeature`

```
git checkout dev
git merge myFeature
```

> And then commit and push again. Is this a right way?

No need to commit again, the successful merge will create the commit.

> Can a branch created from commit?

Yes, as demonstrated in step 1

> What means --track flag in GIT and when i need to use it?

I will refer you to [the `git branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

```
-t, --track
    When creating a new branch, set up branch.<name>.remote and branch.<name>.merge configuration
    entries to mark the start-point branch as "upstream" from the new branch. This configuration will
    tell git to show the relationship between the two branches in git status and git branch -v.
    Furthermore, it directs git pull without arguments to pull from the upstream when the new branch
    is checked out.

    This behavior is the default when the start point is a remote-tracking branch. Set the
    branch.autoSetupMerge configuration variable to false if you want git checkout and git branch to
    always behave as if --no-track were given. Set it to always if you want this behavior when the
    start-point is either a local or remote-tracking branch.
```

> What is the difference between branch and origin/branch?

`branch` should refer to your local copy, and `origin/branch` refers to the copy on the remote server.

> Can somebody explain me about branches?

This is verging on off-topic for SO as too-broad, but here's [a wonderful **free** interactive tutorial](https://www.udacity.com/course/how-to-use-git-and-github--ud775) that should answer this for you in addition to the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) and the aforementioned [`git branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).